Is it possible to prove that iterating this hailstone-resembling algorithm will always end in $1$?
I've been messing with a rule I came up with recently, that resembles the Collatz function in formulation but shares very few practical similarities. Using $p_n$ to represent the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number and $c_n$ to represent the $n^{\text{th}}$ composite number, the formulation is as such:
\begin{cases} 
      \text{if } n \text{ is prime:} & p_n \to p_{n+1} - p_n \\
      \text{if } n \text{ is composite:} & c_n \to c_{n-1} + c_n \\
   \end{cases}
In words, this means, "If the number is prime, take the difference between the number and the next prime number, and if the number is composite, take the sum of the number and the previous composite number." The sequence ends when it gets to $1$. (Because $4$ is the first composite number, we treat $c_0$ as $1$, meaning that $4$ goes to $5$.) Let's use $6$ as an example: because $6$ is composite, it goes to $6 + 4 = 10$; because $10$ is composite, it goes to $10 + 9 = 19$; because $19$ is prime, it goes to $23 - 19 =4$; and continuing this process, the sequence unfolds as:
$$6 \to 10 \to 19 \to 4 \to 5 \to 2 \to 1.$$
These sequences have a tendency to act very erratically. For example, the sequence beginning with $32$ demonstrates many features of this process:
$${\small32 \to 62 \to 122 \to 243 \to 485 \to 969 \to 1937 \to 3873 \to 7745 \to 15489 \to 30977 \to 6 \to 10 \to 19 \to 4 \to 5 \to 2 \to 1.}$$
We can notice several things; first, when we reach an odd number, all the numbers thereafter will be odd until we reach a prime number (since the nearest composite number below an odd number will always be even). In the above sequence, all the numbers from $243$ to $15489$ are composite, and only because $30977$ is prime do we return to an even number. Also, we can see, as the numbers get higher, they grow faster, and the chance of them being prime is much rarer. In fact, when a sequence starts growing, it looks like it'll never stop, at least for a while; the sequence starting with $95$ has $595$ terms, the largest of whom is the $178$-digit prime number $${\scriptsize1487939695262196876907983166454197495251350196192890428923003345454869706240895712896623468784438158657419591298913094265537812046389415279164757669092989298186306341246574002177.}$$
The next prime number is $152$ greater than that, so the next item in the sequence is $152$, after which the sequence rapidly goes to $1$ (through the primes $4817$ and then $101$). Here's a picture of the start of the sequence (easier to see if you open it in a new tab):

It is easy to see that these sequences can rapidly skyrocket, at a rate just barely less than $2^n$. The question is:

Is there a sequence that never ends (that never goes to $1$)? Is there any rigorous way to prove that either all sequences go to $1$ or that one sequence will never reach $1$?

I conjecture that they all go to $1$, but I can't imagine how to go about proving it -- any help would be much appreciated!

"If $n$ is prime, $p_n\to p_{n+1}-p_n$" uses  the one symbol $n$ to mean two different things, which is never a good idea. Please edit appropriately (also for the composite half).

There are divergent sequences that will never reach $1$, for example starting from $78558$.

These can be constructed from Sierpiński numbers - integers $N$ such that $N2^n+1$ is composite for all $n\geq 1$. We will show that by choosing Sierpiński number $N$ such that $N$ and $N+1$ are both composite, the sequence starting with $N+1$ coincides with $N2^n+1$, and as such is increasing. Smallest such example is given by $N=78557$, so starting from $N+1=78558$ gives one such sequence.

Proof. Define the sequence $a_0=N+1$ and $a_{n+1}=T(a_n)$, where $T$ is your iteration map. We will show that for all $n$ both $a_n$ and $a_n-1$ are composite. For $n=0$ this follows from our choice of $N$. For the sake of contradiction assume $n$ is the smallest such that one of $a_n$ and $a_{n}-1$ is a prime. Since all the previous terms satisfied $a_{k+1}=2a_k-1$, this recurrence solves to a closed form $a_n=N2^n+1$ (e.g. by induction). By our assumption one of $a_n$ or $a_n-1$ is a prime. Clearly $a_n-1=N2^n$ is composite. However $a_n=N2^n+1$ is also composite - this is a property of a Sierpiński number $N$. Thus we reached a contradiction and all $a_n$ and $a_n-1$ are composite. Hence the entire sequence is generated by $a_{n+1}=2a_n-1$ and $a_n=N2^n+1$ for $n\geq 0$.
$\square$

Cool! Glad to see this question answered, thanks for your help!

You are welcome!


Is it possible to prove that iterating this hailstone-resembling algorithm will always end in $1$?

Even if it is possible, it is very hard. Indeed, let $m$ be any natural number. The sequence beginning from $2^m+1$ is continued as $2^m+1,2^m+1,\dots$ as far as these numbers $2^k+1$ are composite. But the latter can be prime only when $k$ is a power of $2$ and in this case it is called a Fermat prime. The only known Fermat primes are attained for $k=2^d$ with nonnegative integer $d\le 4$ and whether are there infinitely many Fermat primes is the famous open problem by Eisenstein from 1844. Heuristics suggest that $2^{2^4}+1$ is the last Fermat prime. But if the problem solution is negative and $2^m+1$ is bigger than any Fermat prime then the sequence will increase infinitely.
